# Confused about use of 'HANDLE' in piece of Visual C++ code for Real-Time IIS 7.0 Event Logging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm relatively new to Visual C++.  I'm trying to build a module to consume log events generated by the IIS 7.0 server in order to be able to analyze these logs in real-time.  I found a Microsoft article which provides code that accomplishes the real-time capture:

---

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/581/advanced-logging-for-iis-70---real-time-logging#module

---

After some work, I've gotten this code to compile into a DLL on my machine (64-bit Windows XP with Visual Studio .NET 2008).  I'm curious about the double initiation (?) of the m_hEventLog 'event viewer'.  I've reproduced the constructor and the line in the private section which both seem to create a handle to the event viewer.

The constructor:

```
MyGlobalModule()    
{       
    m_hEventLog = RegisterEventSource( NULL, L"IISADMIN" );    
}

private:    
HANDLE m_hEventLog;
```

---

My question: Why does m_hEventLog need to be declared twice?

Thanks in advance,

-Eric

Comment: It's not being declared twice, is it? It's being declared in the "private:" section and initialized in the constructor.

Comment: does the private section get processed first?  If so, that explains the subsequent assignment in the constructor.  Thanks!

Comment: Seems this is a confusion about fundamental C++ , perhaps exacerbated by usage of this windows type HANDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
private:
HANDLE m_hEventLog;
```

is declaration of the variable `m_hEventLog`. It means that when an object of type `MyGlobalModule` will be declared, that will contain a member named `m_hEventLog`. When the object is *declared*, or in other words, *constructed*, the constructor is called. It executes the following line:

```
m_hEventLog = RegisterEventSource( NULL, L"IISADMIN" );
```

The this line will execute, `RegisterEventSource()` will be called and its return value will be assigned to `m_hEventLog`.

**EDIT**

Consider the following program:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : a(0) {}

    int get_a() const {return a;}
    void set_a(int na) {a = na;}

private:
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

When this program is executed, nothing actually happens for `class A` because there is *no variable <strike>declared</strike> defined of type A*. If the `main()` function is written in this way:

```
int main()
{
    A a;

    return 0;
}
```

then an object of type `A` is *<strike>declared</strike> defined* (provided that compiler didn't optimize anything). It hold an integer inside it (the member variable `a`). `A`'s constructor will be called so that `A` is initialized. And the constructor will initialize `A`'s `a` to 0. Note I used initializer list to initialize `A::a`.

Comment: The constructor will be executed for _defined_ variables. A variable that's only _declared_ (`extern A a`), will not cause a constructor to be called. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration) for more info regarding what's a definition and what's a declaration.

Comment: @sbi: i'm a bit confused by the line "`The C++ standard considers struct x; to be a declaration`" from the post. Is `A a` a declaration or definition or both in my answer?

Comment: @Donato: `type obj;` is the _definition_ of an _object_ (variable). A _declaration_ of an _object_ would be `extern type obj`. `class X { ... };` is the _definition_ of a _class_. `class x;` is a _declaration_ of a _class_ (usually called a "forward declaration", but there are no other class declarations).

Comment: @sbi, uh! poor me. i was reading `struct x;` as `struct X x;`.